# Add data to MNIST dataset

Tags: python, numpy

I am doing a machine learning project to recognize handwritten digits. Actually, I just want to add few more data sets to MNIST but I am unable to do so.

I have done following:

```
n_samples = len(mnist.data)
x = mnist.data.reshape((n_samples, -1))# array of feature of 64 pixel
y = mnist.target                         # Class label from 0-9 as there are digits

img_temp_train=cv2.imread('C:/Users/amuly/Desktop/Soap/crop/2.jpg',0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)

#Now I want to add the img_temp_train to my dataset for training.

X_train=np.append(X_train,img_temp_train.reshape(-1))
y_train=np.append(y_train,[4.0])
```

The length after training is:

- 43904784 (X_train)
- 56001(y_train)

But it should be 56001 for both.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
X_train = np.append(X_train, [img_temp_train], axis=0)
```

You shouldn't be reshaping things willy-nilly without thinking about what you're doing first!

Also, it's usually a better idea to use concatenate:

```
X_train = np.concatenate((X_train, [img_temp_train]), axis=0)
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the X_train.shape is (56000,784) while img_temp_train.shape is (784,)

Comment: Updated. (Forgot to include `axis=0` in the first example.)